# why IdleConnectionMonitorThread need to synchronize

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, synchronized

I see many examples of IdleConnectionMonitorThread using 'synchronized' in implement of 'run'. In my mind, it makes no sense.
The implement in

> edu.uci.ics
>               crawler4j
>               4.2

```
public class IdleConnectionMonitorThread extends Thread {

  private final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr;
  private volatile boolean shutdown;

  public IdleConnectionMonitorThread(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connMgr) {
    super("Connection Manager");
    this.connMgr = connMgr;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!shutdown) {
        synchronized (this) {
          wait(5000);
          // Close expired connections
          connMgr.closeExpiredConnections();
          // Optionally, close connections that have been idle longer than 30 sec
          connMgr.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
      // terminate
    }
  }

  public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();
        }
        log.warn("newPosition: shutdown idleMonitorThread");

    }

}
```

Since in most cases we only have one IdleConnectionMonitorThread and use it in this way, synchronized (this) has no meaning.

```
IdleConnectionMonitorThread idleConnectionMonitorThread = new IdleConnectionMonitorThread(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
```

I wonder the benefit of using 'synchronized', can use implement run in this way (delete the synchronized)

```
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          while (!shutdown) {
              wait(5000);
              // Close expired connections
              connMgr.closeExpiredConnections();
              // Optionally, close connections that have been idle longer than 30 sec
              connMgr.closeIdleConnections(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
          // terminate
        }
      }
```

Comment: You mean why wait instead of sleeping?

Comment: no, There is only one thread, I mean there is no need to use synchronized.

Comment: Don't see methods like "closeExpiredConnections" in version "client5..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) for `Object.wait(long)`.

If you call it when you don't hold the mutex you are waiting on, you will get an exception.  The javadoc states:

> Throws: `IllegalMonitorStateException` - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

In general, locking the mutex in the "wait/notify" protocol is essential to ensure that the shared state that is being managed is visible to all threads that are participating.  In this case the `shutdown` variable is declared as `volatile` so that isn't a concern.  However, the "wait/notify" protocol *requires* locking anyway; see above.

> I wonder the benefit of using `synchronized`, can use implement run in this way (delete the synchronized).

Nope.  If you deleted the `synchronized` you would get an exception.  But you could replace `Object.wait(...)` with `Thread.sleep(...)` ... and then the `synchronized` would be unnecessary.

---

As to the "oddness" of this code, who knows why the author ended up with this.  But does it really matter?  There is an Engineering principle: *"If it ain't broken, don't fix it"*.  Nobody has proposed a reason why this code is broken.

Comment: This code seems strange to me. There's no notifying going on, and it would be bizarre if this connectionmanager thing wasn't designed to be safely called from multiple threads. So who the hell knows what the person who wrote it was thinking?